# How to get a gridlines of pixel

Tags: uv

I have a Minecraft character.
I will wish to work the pixels of my character.
How to get the selection of these pixels ?
As you see, I have the selection of the judgments of characters only.

[image]

Here's what I will wish to obtain:

[image]

Comment: Pleaze ? u_u"
I want to continue

Comment: Il fallait juste appuyer sur la touche "W" -> Subivise =P
Thank you -_-